# Error Hosting Flask App on Heroku ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytrends'

Tags: python, flask, heroku, hosting, web-hosting

I am trying to host an app I built with Flask which uses an unofficial Google Trends API, pytrends. It looks like when I try to create and launch the app the logs show an error about pytrends... I tried downloads the files for pytrends and adding them to my repo but that didn't seem to do anything. Anyone know why this is happening?

```
2020-06-24T18:23:48.282652+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-06-24 18:23:48 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2020-06-24T18:23:48.413340+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-06-24 18:23:48 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2020-06-24T18:23:48.413589+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-06-24 18:23:48 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2020-06-24T18:23:48.544233+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2020-06-24T18:23:48.585724+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2020-06-24T18:30:19.374989+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=stockmkt-app.herokuapp.com request_id=a645683e-4f1c-4198-b6b4-7aabe1a5d391 fwd="190.235.222.251" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-06-24T18:30:20.179671+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=stockmkt-app.herokuapp.com request_id=efcc5ba9-94c6-4ff9-b412-a35e85285e82 fwd="190.235.222.251" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-06-24T18:35:52.622302+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-06-24T18:35:56.505542+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn wsgi:app`
2020-06-24T18:35:59.381830+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-06-24 18:35:59 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
2020-06-24T18:35:59.382937+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-06-24 18:35:59 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:31549 (4)
2020-06-24T18:35:59.383078+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-06-24 18:35:59 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2020-06-24T18:35:59.395639+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-06-24 18:35:59 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2020-06-24T18:35:59.441614+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-06-24 18:35:59 +0000] [11] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11
2020-06-24T18:35:59.871391+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-06-24 18:35:59 +0000] [11] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2020-06-24T18:35:59.871423+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-06-24T18:35:59.871432+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
2020-06-24T18:35:59.871433+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2020-06-24T18:35:59.871433+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 119, in init_process
2020-06-24T18:35:59.871434+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2020-06-24T18:35:59.871434+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 144, in load_wsgi
2020-06-24T18:35:59.871434+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2020-06-24T18:35:59.871437+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2020-06-24T18:35:59.871438+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2020-06-24T18:35:59.871438+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load
2020-06-24T18:35:59.871438+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2020-06-24T18:35:59.871438+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 39, in load_wsgiapp
2020-06-24T18:35:59.871439+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2020-06-24T18:35:59.871439+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 358, in import_app
2020-06-24T18:35:59.871440+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2020-06-24T18:35:59.871440+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2020-06-24T18:35:59.871441+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2020-06-24T18:35:59.871442+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
2020-06-24T18:35:59.871442+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
2020-06-24T18:35:59.871442+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2020-06-24T18:35:59.871442+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
2020-06-24T18:35:59.871443+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
2020-06-24T18:35:59.871443+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
2020-06-24T18:35:59.871443+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/wsgi.py", line 1, in <module>
2020-06-24T18:35:59.871443+00:00 app[web.1]: from app.main import app
2020-06-24T18:35:59.871443+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/app.py", line 3, in <module>
2020-06-24T18:35:59.871444+00:00 app[web.1]: from stocks import kw, term, today, ad, a_s, now, percent_change1, percent_change2, direction, direction1
2020-06-24T18:35:59.871444+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/stocks.py", line 1, in <module>
2020-06-24T18:35:59.871444+00:00 app[web.1]: from pytrends.request import TrendReq
2020-06-24T18:35:59.871444+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytrends'
2020-06-24T18:35:59.871546+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-06-24 18:35:59 +0000] [11] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 11)
2020-06-24T18:35:59.874159+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-06-24 18:35:59 +0000] [10] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2020-06-24T18:35:59.874159+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-06-24T18:35:59.874160+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
2020-06-24T18:35:59.874160+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2020-06-24T18:35:59.874160+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 119, in init_process
2020-06-24T18:35:59.874160+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2020-06-24T18:35:59.874160+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 144, in load_wsgi
2020-06-24T18:35:59.874161+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2020-06-24T18:35:59.874161+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2020-06-24T18:35:59.874161+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2020-06-24T18:35:59.874161+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load
2020-06-24T18:35:59.874162+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2020-06-24T18:35:59.874162+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 39, in load_wsgiapp
2020-06-24T18:35:59.874162+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2020-06-24T18:35:59.874162+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 358, in import_app
2020-06-24T18:35:59.874162+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2020-06-24T18:35:59.874163+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2020-06-24T18:35:59.874163+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2020-06-24T18:35:59.874163+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
2020-06-24T18:35:59.874163+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
2020-06-24T18:35:59.874164+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2020-06-24T18:35:59.874164+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
2020-06-24T18:35:59.874164+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
2020-06-24T18:35:59.874164+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
2020-06-24T18:35:59.874165+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/wsgi.py", line 1, in <module>
2020-06-24T18:35:59.874165+00:00 app[web.1]: from app.main import app
2020-06-24T18:35:59.874165+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/app.py", line 3, in <module>
2020-06-24T18:35:59.874165+00:00 app[web.1]: from stocks import kw, term, today, ad, a_s, now, percent_change1, percent_change2, direction, direction1
2020-06-24T18:35:59.874165+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/stocks.py", line 1, in <module>
2020-06-24T18:35:59.874166+00:00 app[web.1]: from pytrends.request import TrendReq
2020-06-24T18:35:59.874166+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytrends'
2020-06-24T18:35:59.874494+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-06-24 18:35:59 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2020-06-24T18:36:00.014237+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-06-24 18:36:00 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2020-06-24T18:36:00.014451+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-06-24 18:36:00 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2020-06-24T18:36:00.089546+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2020-06-24T18:36:00.139818+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Comment: Did you add `pytrends` in your `requirements.txt` ?

Comment: yes I tried that but still no luck... any other ideas?

Comment: Could you post your requirements file?